# move some data from excel to sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I want to move some data from an Excelfile to my database. I use c#
this is my code:

```
        //conecting to DB
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=ghalamchi;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCmd.Connection = sqlcon;
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlCmd.CommandText = "SP_AddStudent";

        int counter = 0;

         int i = 21;
        {
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Char, 20).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@family", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 80).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@codeM", SqlDbType.Char, 15).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();
            //SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = txb_city.Text;
            //SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@street", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = txb_street.Text;
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Addres", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 150).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@telephon", SqlDbType.NChar, 15).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][5].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@mobile", SqlDbType.NChar, 15).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][6].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@rabet1", SqlDbType.NChar, 15).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@rabet2", SqlDbType.NChar, 15).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][8].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@SchoolName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][9].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@avg", SqlDbType.Char, 6).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][10].ToString();
             SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@returnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            sqlcon.Open();

            SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (SqlCmd.Parameters["@returnValue"].Value.ToString() == "1")
                counter++;

            sqlcon.Close();             
        }
```

in this code , read a specefice row that declare with variable "i". it work correctly .but when i use a for() , for reading all of the rows of an excell file, this code have an error 
this is the error :

> Procedure or function SP_AddStudent has too many arguments specified.

i think this error occured ,because speed of db is low and it can't read an write all of the rows quickly

```
for (int i = 0; i < Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)            
        {
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Char, 20).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@family", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 80).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][2].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@codeM", SqlDbType.Char, 15).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][3].ToString();
            //SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30).Value = txb_city.Text;
            //SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@street", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = txb_street.Text;
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@Addres", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 150).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@telephon", SqlDbType.NChar, 15).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][5].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@mobile", SqlDbType.NChar, 15).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][6].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@rabet1", SqlDbType.NChar, 15).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][7].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@rabet2", SqlDbType.NChar, 15).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][8].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@SchoolName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][9].ToString();
            SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@avg", SqlDbType.Char, 6).Value = Ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][10].ToString();
             SqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@returnValue", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
            sqlcon.Open();

            SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (SqlCmd.Parameters["@returnValue"].Value.ToString() == "1")
                counter++;

            sqlcon.Close();




        }
```

what should i do?
 at the end
i cant speak englishe very well, sorry...

Comment: This is **not** a speed problem. You have more parameters in your c# code then you have specified in your stored procedure. Try translating the error message to your native language (word for word, not by using google translate).

Comment: is this requirement to import data from excel to database using c#? or any other way is possible?

Comment: Probably you overcomplicate things here, there are more straightforward ways to import Excel to SQL Server, see e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/636719/Import-MS-Excel-data-to-SQL-Server-table-using-Csh

Comment: number of parameters is correct, because when i don't use for(), it run correctly

Comment: can you please start your for loop with 1 .

Comment: i start for loop with 1, but nothing changed....

Comment: when i use this for loop , there isn't any problem:
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
that mean , problem start when the code wants to add more than one row from the excel file

Comment: I think you can use Bulk insert then .

Comment: Are you adding all the parameters twice the second time through your loop?

Answer (score 0):

--Here is the code for bulk Insert .write a function to write data in database without Parameter .In procedure you use same temp table to insert data in your actual table

```
public void WriteData()
        {
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString))
            {
                //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions st = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions();

                //GetBulkCopy(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity)
                using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(TempTable, conn);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    bulk.DestinationTableName = "#ImportData";
                    for (Int32 I = 0; I < DTFinal.Columns.Count; I++)
                    {
                        bulk.ColumnMappings.Add(DTFinal.Columns[I].ToString(), DTFinal.Columns[I].ToString());
                    }
                    bulk.WriteToServer(DTFinal);
                    cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.SP_AddStudent", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
                //conn.Open();
                //System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand 

                conn.Close();

            }
        }
```

Comment: I hope you understand the code and modify accordingly .

Answer (score 0):

my Guess was correct
speed of input data was more than the database control, so it cant handel it.
so i put all of the above code in a method(Add_SQL(int row)) an call it with a for loop :

for (int i = 0; i < Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++ )
                Add_SQL(i);

by this way , calling method and doing the code and calling the next method make a delay an data base can manage the data